# Extracting colors in French

Tags: python, csv, colors, text-extraction, french

I have a CSV with some information about products color. Since sometimes some extra details are there, I would like to extract just the color name.
I found out some library but my data are in french so they dont fit those.
I try to do it with Python.

From "transparent blue" I want to just keep "blue"

The table is like :

| Product ref | Color | Sales quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F33 | Bleu transparent | 2 |
| K367 | Ecaille Marron | 1 |

And I am looking to take the "Bleu" (Blue) and "Marron" (brown) to see which colors are the more sale

Comment: What programming language are you using? Can you also provide a more detailed example of the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a translator function and then `apply` this to the column.

here is an example (using the data in the question).

```py
import pandas as pd

# original dataframe
data = {'Product ref': ['F33', 'K367'],
        'Color': ['Bleu transparent', 'Ecaille Marron'],
        'Sales quantity': [2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def translate(french):
    ''' translating function '''
    if 'Bleu' in french:
        return 'blue'
    
    if 'Marron' in french:
        return 'brown'
    
    return '-'

# apply the result
df['english'] = df['Color'].apply(translate)
print(df)
```

This is the result:

```
  Product ref             Color  Sales quantity english
0         F33  Bleu transparent               2    blue
1        K367    Ecaille Marron               1  brown
```

**Note**:
You could use a much more sophistocated translating and matching function (for example `googletrans`). The example above is a working example.

Comment: What i am scare about with this idea is there are at least 40 different colors ... then the translate fonction would be pretty long ...

Comment: @MarieA,  yes, it would, which is why i showed only how to implement the "translator" function correctly (and efficiently). The reality is that you would use pattern matching & translation, but this would be the subject of another question.

Comment: @MarieA,  a quick (and also computational fast) solution to having many colours would be to implement a hash table (python dictionary) in place of the if statements that i used in the example...  it is relatively simple to implement.